# How to reverse a singly linked list using recursive approach in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

I wonder how to reverse a singly linked list using recursive approach in Python.

This is LeetCode problem [206. Reverse Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/description/):

> Given the `head` of a singly linked list, reverse the list, and return *the reversed list*.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> [image]
>
> **Input:** `head = [1,2,3,4,5]`
> **Output:** `[5,4,3,2,1]`

Most people use an iterative approach, which is quite classic and easily comprehensible. However, I have come across a recursive method which bewilders me:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        # recursive call
        if not head:
            return None

        newHead = head
        if head.next:
            newHead = self.reverseList(head.next)
            head.next.next = head
        head.next = None
        print(newHead)
        return newHead
```

For instance, if I input [1,2,3], I would manually work out the process as follows, which seems intuitively right but I cannot convince myself that it will return the right thing through recursive calls of `reverselist`. Can you kindly tell me why? Thanks very much!

[image: my draft of what the above recursive calls would work]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you could visualise the reversal of linked list 1→2→3:

We start with:

```
 head
  │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

The first recursive call receives `head.next`, and will have its own local names. To distinguish those local names from the names we alread have in the original execution of `reverseList`, I'll add accents to the names, where the number of acccents denotes the recursion depth. So at the first recursive call we can visualise the situation like this:

```
 head            head'
  │               │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

And at the second level recursive call:

```
 head            head'           head'' newHead''
  │               │               │      │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐   ┌─┴──────┴──┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

This second-level recursive execution will not enter the `if` block and just set the `next` attribute of `head''` to `None` (which it already was) and return `newHead''`.

Back to the first recursive execution that returned reference is assigned to `newHead'`, so we have this:

```
 head            head'           newHead'
  │               │               │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

In this recursive execution it is the first time we execute `head.next.next = head`, acting on `head'`. So we get:

```
 head            head'           newHead'
  │               │               │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: ┐   │
│           │   │           ├───────────┘   │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

And then `head'` gets `None` for its `next` attribute:

```
 head            head'           newHead'
  │               │               │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: None│   │ next: ┐   │
│           │   │           ├───────────┘   │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

Finally this first recursive execution returns `newHead'`.

The original execution receives this reference and assigns it to its own `newHead`:

```
 head                            newHead
  │                               │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: None│   │ next: ┐   │
│           │   │           ├───────────┘   │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

Again, `head.next.next = head` is executed:

```
 head                            newHead
  │                               │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ┐   │   │ next: ┐   │
│           ├───────────┘   ├───────────┘   │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

And finally, `head.next` is set to `None` and `newHead` is returned:

```
                                 (returned)
                                  │
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: None│   │ next: ┐   │   │ next: ┐   │
│           ├───────────┘   ├───────────┘   │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

...which is the reversed list.

Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Good answer. Just curious: what SW (or site) do you use for these nice ASCII graphs? :)

Comment: Nothing special. I have these box-drawing characters mapped to my keyboard and I also have some of these boxes ready-made in a text file.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your graphs are awesome. I just wonder whether the purpose of having newHead is to return the last node in the original sequence by passing it n times through newHead = self.reverseList(head.next)?

Comment: Yes, all `newHead` local variables get to reference the tail node. While unwinding the recursion this reference bubbles up to the original caller.